# I want to remove stop words and using anti_join but is getting error

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stop-words, anti-join

My R code is as follows: -

```
data_review2 <- data %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, reviewText) %>%
  anti_join(stop_words)  .
```

This code is showing error like this:

```
Error in `auto_copy()`:
! `x` and `y` must share the same src.
ℹ `x` is a <tbl_df/tbl/data.frame> object.
ℹ `y` is the string "i|me|my|myself|we|our|ours|...".
ℹ Set `copy = TRUE` if `y` can be copied to the same source as `x` (may be
  slow).
```

I have tried everyting nothing works. Someone please suggest alternative

I have tried using the filter() function, made the local data as well but it is not working. I want to remove the stop words

Comment: This is tricky to answer just now as we can't reproduce your error. Aim to load all packages you're using (e.g. `tidytext` and `dplyr`) and give a sample of your dataframe `data` (or a simulated example which gives the same results). `data` should be a `data.frame` with a column called `reviewText`?

Comment: Ok I am trying LDA.
It is working fine if I do not want to remove the stop words. The code for same is:-
data_review <- data %>%
unnest_tokens(word, reviewText)
head(data_review)
But if I wish to remove stop-words, this error is popping regularly. I have tried a few things but nothing works.

Comment: _Reproducible_ includes: (1) code attempted, including explicitly listing non-base packages; and (2) sample data, preferably in an unambiguous format such as using `dput(.)` (pasting the console output of a frame is _not_ unambiguous). Please read https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for a bit more discussion about this. My guess is that `stop_words` is a vector, in which case `dplyr::anti_join` won't work, it is not equipped to do that. See [`?anti_join`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter-joins.html), it needs two frames.

Comment: `tidytext::stop_words` as imported by the package is a tibble. If you've defined your own set of stop words then it should mimic the structure of that.